# Receiving strangers strings in target window from PostMessage api

Tags: c#, postmessage

I have a Remote Administration Tool, and I'm with a trouble when receives strings in any window with PostMessage api. The strings are sent through of `TextBox` componente in Server application.

For example, the word **Coder** in StackOverflow window stays like this:

[image]

and my code that I'm using is this:

***Server application***

```
       private void tEnviarTexto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String message = String.Format("<|MSG|>{0}", tEnviarMSG.Text);
            ListViewItem item = listView_clients.FocusedItem;
            String clientId = item.Name;
            RemoteClient client = this.remoteClientManager.GetClientById(clientId);
            if (client != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.mreMessage.WaitOne();
                    client.queueMessage.AddMessage(message);
                    tEnviarMSG.Text = "";
                }

                catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            }
        }
```

***Client application***

```
       public void EnviatextoHWND(string texto)
        {
            foreach (char caractere in texto)
            {
                int charValue = caractere;
                string hexValue = charValue.ToString("X");
                IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)caractere);

                string valor = val.ToString();

                if (valor == "66") // Letra B no Operador
                {
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_BACK), new IntPtr(0));
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_BACK), new IntPtr(0));

                }
                else if (valor == "83") // Letra S no Operador
                {
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_SPACE), new IntPtr(0));
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_SPACE), new IntPtr(0));

                }
                else
                {

                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, val, new IntPtr(0));
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
                    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, val, new IntPtr(0));

                } 
            }
        }
```

and usage:

```
public void CommunicationProc()
    {

      while (this.Connected)
        {
         else if (message.IndexOf("<|MSG|>") == 0)
          {
            String[] strSplit = value.Split(MenuRemoteClient.separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string msg = strSplit[0]; // content from a TextBox on Server application

                   if (this.remotedNav)
                     {
                       Thread SendTextoHWND = new Thread(() => EnviatextoHWND(msg));
                           SendTextoHWND.Start();
                            }
                        }
                }
             }
```

So, how solve it?

Any suggestions or guidance here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
             //   PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, val, new IntPtr(0));
                PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
            //    PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, val, new IntPtr(0));
```